# IndexError: List index out of range, only when performing operations 2 list items - Python

Tags: python, list

I have the following code:

```
infile = open("sitin.txt", "r")
r = int(infile.readline().split()[0])
s = int(infile.readline().split()[1])
totalseats = r * s
print(totalseats)
```

my input file, "sitin.txt" is a text file with nothing but `10 10`. Printing either r or s by itself returns the correct value, and printing either r or s multiplied by 10 returns the correct value, but this code, attempting to multiply r and s returns "IndexError: list index out of range". What is happening here?

Comment: Are you expecting `infile.readline()` to return the same line each time you call it?

Comment: print infile and check if it has 2 values

Comment: @khelwood the file will always be two space seperated integers, so I am expecting it to be basically the same.

Comment: @Lucian print(infile.read()) prints `10 10`, so yes it has two values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you read your input file too many times; you will get `r` for the first line; `s` for the second line (and so on)... fix:

```
infile = open("sitin.txt", "r")
split = infile.readline().split()  # read once only!
r = int(split[0])
s = int(split[1])
totalseats = r * s
print(totalseats)
```

you may need to check that `split` has the correct form for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your readline() the "cursor" moves to the next line. Thus you should probably only read that line once or shift back offset. Try doing this instead:

```
infile = open("sitin.txt", "r")
t = infile.readline().split()
r = int(t[0])
s = int(t[1])
totalseats = r * s
print(totalseats)
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be doing `readline()` twice, which is going to read two lines. Do it once, grab the results, split that. Also, would help to put your file access inside a with, so that the file is automatically closed for you after reading, not left open as a dangling resource. E.g.:

```
with open("sitin.txt", "r") as infile:
    line = infile.readline()
r, s = map(int, line.split())
totalseats = r * s
print(totalseats)
```